# tkinter ttk style Layout not found

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Getting an error on the following code.   Keep looking at examples and re-evaluating code but cannot really spot any reason this shouldn't run.  Is there anything incorrect such that the `'mRRed'` layout cannot be found?  (And I'm sure the subsequent)...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainFrame:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(parent,padding='3 3 12 12')
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.mRRed = ttk.Style()
        self.mRBlue = ttk.Style()
        self.mPurple = ttk.Style()
        self.mPink = ttk.Style()
        self.mSCyan = ttk.Style()
        self.mVYellow = ttk.Style()
        self.mGreen  = ttk.Style()

        self.mRRed.configure("mRRed",background="#E61E50")
        self.mRBlue.configure("mRBlue",background="#0F69AF")
        self.mPurple.configure("mPurple",background="#503291")
        self.mPink.configure("mPink",background="#EB3C96")
        self.mSCyan.configure("mSCyan",background="#2BDECD")
        self.mVYellow.configure("mVYellow",background="#FFC832")
        self.mGreen.configure("mGreen",background="#149B5F")


        self.toolRibbon    = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mRRed')
        self.subtoolRibbon = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mRBlue')
        self.titleFrame    = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mPruple')
        self.contentFrame  = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mPink')
        self.optionRibbon  = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mSCyan')
        self.statusFrame   = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mVYellow')
        self.infoFrame     = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mGreen')

        self.toolRibbon.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.subtoolRibbon.grid(column=0,row=1)
        self.titleFrame.grid(column=1,row=1)
        self.contentFrame.grid(column=1,row=2)
        self.optionRibbon.grid(column=1,row=3)
        self.statusFrame.grid(column=1,row=4)
        self.infoFrame.grid(column=4,row=1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("test")

main = MainFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        43 root.title("test")
>        44 
>   ---> 45 main = MainFrame(root)
>        46 root.mainloop()
>
> in **init**(self, parent)
>        24 
>        25 
>   ---> 26         self.toolRibbon    = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mRRed')
>        27         self.subtoolRibbon = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mRBlue')
>        28         self.titleFrame    = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mPruple')
>
> D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\ttk.py in **init**(self, master,
>   **kw)
>       740             borderwidth, relief, padding, width, height
>       741         """
>   --> 742         Widget.**init**(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
>       743 
>       744
>
> D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\ttk.py in **init**(self, master,
>   widgetname, kw)
>       557             # Load tile now, if needed
>       558             _load_tile(master)
>   --> 559         tkinter.Widget.**init**(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
>       560 
>       561
>
> D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\tkinter__init__.py in **init**(self, master,
>   widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)    2297             del cnf[k]    2298
>   self.tk.call(
>   -> 2299             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))    2300         for k, v in classes:    2301
>   k.configure(self, v)
>
> TclError: Layout mRRed not found

Comment: If you're going to use them in a `Label` they need the `.TLabel` suffix. So `mRRed.TLabel`, etc.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  Thanks!  Now on to getting it work how I hoped :-D

Comment: @Axe319 could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: @TheMaker I added it as an answer and included an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ttk.Style()` follows the naming convention of `T<widget name>` for user created styles. This is actually isn't really in the python `tkinter` docs other than the fact that they use the naming convention in the examples but never explain it.

So in short, if you want to apply the style to a `Frame` widget you would need to use the suffix `.TFrame` in your style name.

I also noticed, I misread your question and was under the impression you were using a `Label` and not a `Frame`.

I added some `Label`s to demonstrate the effect but in your example, your code would be:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainFrame:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(parent,padding='3 3 12 12')
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.mRRed = ttk.Style()
        self.mRBlue = ttk.Style()
        self.mPurple = ttk.Style()
        self.mPink = ttk.Style()
        self.mSCyan = ttk.Style()
        self.mVYellow = ttk.Style()
        self.mGreen  = ttk.Style()

        self.mRRed.configure("mRRed.TFrame",background="#E61E50")
        self.mRBlue.configure("mRBlue.TFrame",background="#0F69AF")
        self.mPurple.configure("mPurple.TFrame",background="#503291")
        self.mPink.configure("mPink.TFrame",background="#EB3C96")
        self.mSCyan.configure("mSCyan.TFrame",background="#2BDECD")
        self.mVYellow.configure("mVYellow.TFrame",background="#FFC832")
        self.mGreen.configure("mGreen.TFrame",background="#149B5F")


        self.toolRibbon    = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mRRed.TFrame',borderwidth=4)
        self.subtoolRibbon = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mRBlue.TFrame',borderwidth=4)
        self.titleFrame    = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mPurple.TFrame',borderwidth=4)
        self.contentFrame  = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mPink.TFrame',borderwidth=4)
        self.optionRibbon  = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mSCyan.TFrame',borderwidth=4)
        self.statusFrame   = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mVYellow.TFrame',borderwidth=4)
        self.infoFrame     = ttk.Frame(self.frame, style='mGreen.TFrame',borderwidth=4)

        self.toolRibbon.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.subtoolRibbon.grid(column=0,row=1)
        self.titleFrame.grid(column=1,row=1)
        self.contentFrame.grid(column=1,row=2)
        self.optionRibbon.grid(column=1,row=3)
        self.statusFrame.grid(column=1,row=4)
        self.infoFrame.grid(column=4,row=1)

        self.test = ttk.Label(self.optionRibbon, text='cyan test')
        self.test.pack()

        self.test2 = ttk.Label(self.contentFrame, text='pink test')
        self.test2.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("test")

main = MainFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Man!  Yeah, I acutally have had a hard time tracking down good documentation for some of the tk stuff but found a good tutorial and actually made solid headway in my project!  Thanks.